# Deserializing JSON into string array OR datatable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

```
string json = {"house":"#21-3-157/18, Sri Vaibhav","loc":"Subash nagar,Bolar","country":"India"}
```

getting error while deserialize mentioned json string in array

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List because the type requires a
>   JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I've tried many different ways of doing this, each time failed. please help.

Comment: Please show us the type you are deserialising into.

Comment: @Mamta Apraj,Upload your code

Comment: It would help us understand your problem if you could post few of those "many different ways" you tried.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your json snippet there simply is no list data in it. You could probably parse this into some object containing the properties "house", "loc" and "country" but not into a specific list type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NewtonsoftJson](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to parse json data easily without creating concrete class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

dynamic parse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json );
string house = parse.house.Value;
etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Example from https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

```
string json = @"[
  {
    'Title': 'Json.NET is awesome!',
    'Author': {
      'Name': 'James Newton-King',
      'Twitter': '@JamesNK',
      'Picture': '/jamesnk.png'
    },
    'Date': '2013-01-23T19:30:00',
    'BodyHtml': '&lt;h3&gt;Title!&lt;/h3&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Content!&lt;/p&gt;'
  }
]";

dynamic blogPosts = JArray.Parse(json);

dynamic blogPost = blogPosts[0];

string title = blogPost.Title;

Console.WriteLine(title);
// Json.NET is awesome!

string author = blogPost.Author.Name;

Console.WriteLine(author);
// James Newton-King

DateTime postDate = blogPost.Date;

Console.WriteLine(postDate);
// 23/01/2013 7:30:00 p.m.
```

Another example without dynamic https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is not in a format to convert to JSON string array. If you want to Deserialize JSON string to List then your format should be like below,

```
 string json = "[\"house\",\"loc\"]";
```

In you want your string to Desrialize to array then you need corresponding entity like below,

```
public class Address
{
    public string House { get; set; }
    public string Loc { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should deserialize to that type,

```
string json = "[{\"house\":\"#21-3-157/18,Sri Vaibhav\",\"loc\":\"Subash nagar,Bolar\",\"country\":\"India\"}]";
  List<Address> array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(json);
```